# Why is the value you get from heapq.heappop(H) different from the value you get from H[0]?

Tags: python, heap

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [295. Find Median from Data Stream](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-median-from-data-stream/):

> The **median** is the middle value in an ordered integer list. If the size of the list is even, there is no middle value and the median is the mean of the two middle values.
>
> - For example, for `arr = [2,3,4]`, the median is `3`.
> - For example, for `arr = [2,3]`, the median is `(2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5`.
>
> Implement the `MedianFinder` class:
>
> - `MedianFinder()` initializes the `MedianFinder` object.
> - `void addNum(int num)` adds the integer `num` from the data stream to the data structure.
> - `double findMedian()` returns the median of all elements so far.
>   Answers within 10-5 of the actual answer will be accepted.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> MedianFinder medianFinder = new MedianFinder();
> medianFinder.addNum(1);    // arr = [1]
> medianFinder.addNum(2);    // arr = [1, 2]
> medianFinder.findMedian(); // return 1.5 (i.e., (1 + 2) / 2)
> medianFinder.addNum(3);    // arr[1, 2, 3]
> medianFinder.findMedian(); // return 2.0
> ```

For this question, I am adding numbers to a heap and then later use the smallest one to do some operations.

When I tried to do the operation, I found out that my heap returns a different value when doing `heapq.heappop(self.small)` than when doing `self.small[0]`.

Could you please explain this to me? Any hint is much appreciated.

(Every number in `self.small` is added using `heapq.heappush`)

Here is my code when it works:

```
class MedianFinder:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.small, self.large = [], [] 

    def addNum(self, num): 
        heapq.heappush(self.small, -1 * num) 
        if (self.small and self.large) and -1 * self.small[0] > self.large[0]: 
            val = -1 * heapq.heappop(self.small) 
            heapq.heappush(self.large, val) 
        if len(self.small) > len(self.large) + 1: 
            val = -1 * heapq.heappop(self.small) 
            heapq.heappush(self.large, val) 
        if len(self.large) > len(self.small) + 1: 
            val = -1 * heapq.heappop(self.large) 
            heapq.heappush(self.small, val)  

    def findMedian(self): 
        if len(self.small) > len(self.large): 
            return -1 * self.small[0] 
        elif len(self.small) < len(self.large): 
            return self.large[0] 
        else: 
            return (-1 * self.small[0] + self.large[0]) / 2
```

For the last line, if I change:

```
-1 * self.small[0] + self.large[0]
```

into:

```
-1 * heapq.heappop(self.small) + heapq.heappop(self.large)
```

then the tests fail.

Why would that be any different?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change `-1 * self.small[0] + self.large[0]` into `-1 * heapq.heappop(self.small) + heapq.heappop(self.large)` then it will still work **the first time** `findMedian` is called, but when it is called again, it will return (in general) a different result. The reason is that with `heappop`, you *remove* a value from the heap. This should not happen, as this changes the data that a *next* call of `findMedian` will have to deal with. `findMedian` is supposed to leave the data structure unchanged.

Note how the challenge says this:

> double findMedian() returns the median of all elements **so far**.

I highlight the last two words. These indicate that `findMedian` is not (only) called when the whole stream of data has been processed, but will be called several times *during* the processing of the data stream. That makes it crucial that `findMedian` does not modify the data structure, and so `heappop` should not be used.